# How to detect IE7 using jQuery.support

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

The lowest browser my application supports is IE 7.  I have some code that works fine in IE 8, but needs to be avoided in IE 7.  There are a ton of questions/answers on here that indicate how to detect IE 7 with `.browser` but none that indicate how to detect only IE 7 with `.support`.  The jQuery page detailing [.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) does not make it clear which supported features are present in which browsers, so not getting much help there.

Comment: I think this is one of the cases where checking the user agent string (= detecting based on *name* and not *features*) may be the right way to go.

Comment: Look at this question:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165489/how-to-detect-ie7-with-jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165489/how-to-detect-ie7-with-jquery

Comment: @weexpectedTHIS ah, yeah, saw both before I posted.  Both use `.browser` which is deprecated.

Comment: `.browser` is deprecated for the **exact same reason** that you're trying to use it for. The *new standard* is to use proper feature detection instead of sniffing userAgent strings or blocking solely older versions of IE. It is very possible that someone may have Firefox 2 installed or some hipster browser that has absolutely no HTML5 support, that's why simply testing for older versions of IE is deprecated.

Comment: What is the hack code you are using for IE7? Maybe if you showed that, we could give you a better solution.

Comment: Also, unfortunately `jQuery.support` is populated on every page load and used mostly internally by the jQuery core - it only has the required tests for the core to run, and some properties may be removed in future to reduce the init overhead. **tl;dr:** `.support` is not a full feature detection utility and (IMO) not reliable for the long term if you plan on upgrading jQuery often. Modernizr is a library for that purpose, but if you need to detect just a very few features, you can update the post with those (as commented by epascarello) and it'd be easier to provide a proper answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect IE7 and IE8 using jQuery.support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890460/how-to-detect-ie7-and-ie8-using-jquery-support)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason they deprecated .browser is to try to encourage us to test for features instead of browsers.

However.. if you still need to...

Have you considered using H5BP's conditional `<html>` trick and then just testing for that? Header:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then in jQuery,

```
$(function() {
    if( !$('html').hasClass('lt-ie8') ) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: I have seen this code before, but didn't realize what it was doing.  Is there any caveat to doing browser detection like this?

Comment: I couldn't say for sure, but H5BP is created (and audited) by people a lot smarter than me, so that's a good indication it's ok. More details here: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.0.0/doc/html.md

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly always better to identify the features you are targeting in IE8 and use "feature detection" to see if they are available (by testing the feture's functionality) and if they are not available, then use alternate code (for IE7 or any other browser without that feature).

If you offer more specifics on the functionality that doesn't work in IE7, we could help you solve this problem with feature detection, not browser version detection.

Comment: Kinda the same problem with IE 8.  The jQuery `.support` page does not do a good job of indicating what features are available in what browsers so I don't know how to narrow down that a browser is IE 8 using `.support`.

Comment: @typoknig - I'm talking about doing your own feature detection code, not relying on undocumented things in jQuery so I'm not talking about using jQuery.support at all.  It's easy to detect most features yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the API for $.browser?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/#jQuery-browser-version2

But there is a reason why it is deprecated, it is a bad thing to do. You should sniff using feature detection.

Comment: Yeah, I know using `.browser` is bad, that is why I posted the question :)