# How do I properly apply IE conditionals on the html tag for non-IE browsers like Firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to apply the technique recommended here for IE detection in jQuery:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3165521/1093087

What I'm unclear about is how to set the `html` tag for non-IE browsers.

This is what I currently have in my template:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
```

Is this what I should replace it with:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<!--[if lt IE 8><html class="lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
```

Is IE going to be confused by two `html` tags if I do it that way?

Comment: If you want to, sure. "Should" depends on your needs. [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com) [does it slightly differently now.](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6" lang="en-US" 
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                        > <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7" lang="en-US" 
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                        > <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en-US" 
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                        > <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9" lang="en-US" 
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                        > <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

You will have CSS for each instance to customize stuff.

Comment: This worked for me. Then, to confirm, Firefox and Chrome can properly interpret this line: `<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->`?